# alpine krb5 install kerberos commands missing in docker container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I have created a docker  image based on alpine 3.8 that includes krb5. I can then create a container and I can see that   krb5  packages are installed  but  none of the kerberos  commands are in the /bin  e.g kinit klist

I also included all the listed dependencies in the image build  but struggling to understand why the commands are missing ?

Comment: Hi @ScubaMan, this question seems more suitable to the Unix & Linux StackExchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please also post your Dockerfile. That way, it'll be easier to see what's going on.